# NEventStore - decrypt and deserialize stared event data

Tags: c#, neventstore

I'm trying [NEventStore](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore). I started example project and I created some events and saved to database. But in database I see encrypted data only and I cant identify correctness of my stored events. I tried to turn off all settings about encryption but nothing changed.

My init code :

```
var init = Wireup.Init()
                         .LogToOutputWindow()
                         .UsingInMemoryPersistence()
                         .UsingSqlPersistence("EventStore") // Connection string is in app.config
                         .WithDialect(new MsSqlDialect())
                         .EnlistInAmbientTransaction() // two-phase commit
                         .InitializeStorageEngine()
                         .TrackPerformanceInstance("example")
                         .UsingJsonSerialization()
                         //.Compress()
                         //.EncryptWith(EncryptionKey)
                         .HookIntoPipelineUsing(new[] {new AuthorizationPipelineHook()})
                         .UsingSynchronousDispatchScheduler()
                         .DispatchTo(new DelegateMessageDispatcher(DispatchCommit))
                         .Build();
```

I tried to do it in SQL with casting varbinary to varchar by `cast([Payload] as varchar(max)` but I didn't receive clean data as well.

How I can read NEventStore data in readable form please?

Comment: I thought the payload was saved in a binary format no matter the serialization format?

Comment: Did you try truncating your table after you turned off compression/encryption and re-creating some event data? When I start with an empty event store I can use the cast as varchar trick and read the headers/payload just fine. They obviously aren't stored in strict json format because they're prefixed with a few odd non-ascii characters, but it's good enough for "eyeball validation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast Payload column to XML:

```
SELECT TOP 10 CAST(Payload AS XML), *
  FROM [dbo].[Commits]
```

Even though the payload is actually JSON, I get the correct result, e.g.

```
[{"Headers":{},"Body":"Test"}]
```

Obviously, that does not work for compressed or encrypted data.